# Deploying Rails applications with Passenger and Nginx to VPS (EC2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, capistrano, passenger

I've developed a couple of applications which I'm ready to deploy. To do so, I've configured Capistrano and I'm already able to run `cap deploy`, which runs properly. However, I'm totally lost as to how to continue from here. My setup is EC2 + Rails 3.2 + Ruby 1.9.3 + Passenger + Nginx (the one Passenger installs first time you try to start it) + Capistrano.

Until now, I just ran `passenger start` on my app root folder, which would start passenger on port 3000, and I would start the second app on port 3001. Now, what I need is to have this 2 apps under 2 different domains, say www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com.

1. How am I supposed to start the servers now? I can go to the respective `current` folders that Capistrano created and run something like `passenger start -e production -p 3001 -d` and it starts running as a daemon, but, shouldn't capistrano take care of this? All I see is that, on each deploy, it touches the restart.txt file and that forces a "soft restart", which is not enough (as far as I know) if you've changed gems. Shouldn't Capistrano be starting and stopping Passenger, not me?
2. How do I run the 2 apps on 2 domains? As far as I know, you can't point a domain to a port, and all I've managed to do now is to run 1 of the applications by running Passenger on port 80 with `rvmsudo`, but of course this only works for 1 application. After searching a bit I've found something about Nginx Virtual Servers. How do you do this? I mean, I have never touched anything specific to Nginx, just Passenger! Am I supposed to forget about Passenger and deal with Nginx as a service? How?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to start servers there's a specific cap command to start servers, but i don't know much about capistrano, just played with it a little bit before.

As for the second part, this is where nginx takes part, nginx will handle forwarding each domain to the specific port, using [proxy_pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass), take a look at this example

```
server {
    server_name: example1.com;
    proxy_pass: http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
server {
    server_name: example2.com;
    proxy_pass: http://127.0.0.1:3001;
}
```

Comment: But how do I start nginx then? Will I have 2 passengers and 1 nginx running?

Comment: Not sure, but i believe so, when you use rack server you start one for each app correct? unless it's same app serving both sites.

Comment: I run "passenger start" on the root folder of each app, yes.

Comment: when you run your server ip with port, does it work ? `example.com:3000`  or `xx.xx.xx.xx:3000`

Comment: I have an elastic IP associated to my instance on EC2, and yes, myip:3000 and myip:3001 are working.

Comment: try ` sudo service nginx status` on ssh